# dynamically set params are not posted using httpClient in angular 5

Tags: angular

I am using angular 5 and am trying to post some data to an api. Following is what I have done so far:

This code works perfectly:

```
var params = new HttpParams()
  .set('addresses[0][latitude]', 90.64318211857652)
  .set('addresses[0][longitude]', 30.86662599723718)
  .set('addresses[1][latitude]', 90.622619801960056)
  .set('addresses[1][longitude]', 30.91368305099104)
  .set('transport_type', 'motorbike')
  .set('has_return', 0)
  .set('delay', 0);
return this.http.post(url, params, {headers: headers});
```

but since I need to get them dynamically from a form I need to do the following which posts nothing to the server:

```
var params = new HttpParams();
for(let address of p.addresses){
  params.set(address.addLatLng, address.val);
}
params.set('transport_type', p.transport_type);
params.set('has_return', p.has_return);
params.set('delay', p.delay);

return this.http.post(url, params, {headers: headers});
```

This is the result of `console.log(p)`:

```
addresses: Array(4)
0: {addLatLng: "addresses[0][latitude]", val: 90.67102482549417}
1: {addLatLng: "addresses[0][longitude]", val: 30.84517466245563}
2: {addLatLng: "addresses[1][latitude]", val: 90.58590327086768}
3: {addLatLng: "addresses[1][longitude]", val: 30.92026791653143}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
delay: 0
has_return 0
transport_type: "motorbike"
```

Comment: Well start by making a `console.log(p)` and show us the result.

Comment: @trichetriche, Updated question!

Comment: Did you do it in your service ? (dumb question, but just to be sure)

Comment: Yes, This code is in the service!

Comment: Could you try replacing your `set` with an `append` ? Also, make a console log of your HttpParams object, so that we know if the issue with the object or with the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Https Params are immutable. Try that

```
var params = new HttpParams();
for(let address of p.addresses){
  params = params.set(address.addLatLng, address.val);
}
params = params.set('transport_type', p.transport_type)
.set('has_return', p.has_return)
.set('delay', p.delay);

return this.http.post(url, params, {headers: headers});
```

Comment: Thank you Thats it.

Comment: I consider that the answer is wrong, you use httpParams to send data!!

Answer (score -1):

Why use HttpParams?, the sintax for httpClient.post is httpClient.post(url,body,[options]). where body is a object.

NOT confussed with params. the httpParams, see https://angular.io/guide/http#url-parameters is used to change the url. Your solucion works because you don't use httpParams in the form of

```
this.http.post(url, params, {
   headers: headers,
   params:params
   });
```

you can do

```
//A simple object
var data= {
   'addresses0latitude': 90.64318211857652,
   'addresses0longitude': 30.86662599723718,
    'addresses1latitude': 90.622619801960056,
    'addresses1longitude': 30.91368305099104,
    'transport_type', 'motorbike',
    'has_return': 0,
    'delay': 0
}
return this.http.post(url, data, {headers: headers});
```